# Asterisk: Configure the Server header field

Tags: asterisk

How do I modify the *Server* header field in responses by Asterisk?

By default, it includes the release number and the package name:

- Server: Asterisk PBX 13.14.1~dfsg-2+deb9u3
- Server: Asterisk PBX 11.13.1~dfsg-2+deb8u5
- Server: Asterisk PBX 8.13.1~dfsg1-3+deb7u8

At least, I would like to hide the package name.

Comment: Try setting the `useragent` setting in `sip.conf`. Nothing seems to mention being able to change the Server header, but there is a single reference to `add_header(resp, "Server", global_useragent);` in the SIP source.

Comment: Good point! There are settings for the SIP and PJSIP drivers.